# Issue in Firebase Crashlytics setup iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to FirebaseCrashlytics in my app but stuck in 3rd step.

[image]

I am crashing app at

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCrashlytics

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let testarry = [1, 3, 5]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // crash app
        print(testarry[5])
    }
}
```

Run Script

[image]

Even after

Build and run your app

Stop the app from Xcode

Open the app manually from your device or simulator.

Third step is not passing

in xcode console getting output like
[image]

Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: Run the app directly, not via Xcode. And then fire it up a second time (presumably w/out crash), so it gets chance to upload crash report.

Comment: I did but still 3rd step is not passing, not able to see crashlytics dashboard

Comment: What do you mean by “3rd step is not passing”? What is the “3rd step”? My point is that you have shared a screen snapshot with Xcode and the `(lldb)` prompt. That means you ran it from Xcode. But as your list says, you should “Open the app manually from your device or simulator,” not run it from Xcode.

Comment: By the way, did you do `FirebaseApp.configure()` in your app delegate like [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios#firebase-crashlytics-sdk_9) describe?

Answer (score 1):

Your upload runscript does not look correct, try following [this format](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios#firebase-crashlytics-sdk_9). Also, make sure your google services file is in your app.